# How can I change the "Cell padding" per Script

Tags: google-apps-script, string-formatting, google-docs-api, cellpadding

I have create a very simply Google-Script to add a table into a Google Docs:

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter();
body.clear();

var cells = [
['Cell1', 'Cell2', 'Cell3', 'Cell4'],
['Cell5', 'Cell6', 'Cell7', 'Cell8'],
];

var myT = body.appendTable(cells);

var style ={};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Verdana';

myT.setAttributes(style);
myT.setColumnWidth(0, 178.661);
myT.setColumnWidth(1, 106.9681);
myT.setColumnWidth(2, 74.6011);
```

The script works fine. Now I get this question:

How can I change the "Cell Padding" from the Table?
How can I the font or the color from a defined field (e.g. col 2 row 2)?

Answer (score 1):

i don´t find any way to change the "Cell padding" but here is a "way out":

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getFooter();
  body.clear();

  var cells = [
  ['', '', '', ''],
  ];

  var myT = body.appendTable(cells);

  var style ={};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Verdana';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 6;

  myT.setAttributes(style);
  myT.setColumnWidth(0, 178.661);
  myT.setColumnWidth(1, 106.9681);
  myT.setColumnWidth(2, 74.6011);  

  //Col 1
  myT.getCell(0, 0).clear()
  var txt = myT.getCell(0, 0).editAsText();
  txt.setText("Text1\nText1\nText1");

  txt.setBold(0, 45, true);
  txt.setBold(91, 102, true);
  txt.setForegroundColor(150, txt.getText().length-1, '#82E600');

  //Col 2
  myT.getCell(0, 1).clear()
  var txt = myT.getCell(0, 1).editAsText();
  txt.setText("Text2\n\nText2\nText2");

  txt.setBold(0, 8, true);
  txt.setBold(52, 66, true);  

  //Col 3
  myT.getCell(0, 2).clear()
  var txt = myT.getCell(0, 2).editAsText();
  txt.setText("Text3\n\nText3");

  txt.setBold(0, 12, true);  

  //Col 4
  myT.getCell(0, 3).clear()
  var txt = myT.getCell(0, 3).editAsText();
  txt.setText("Text4\n\nText4");

  txt.setBold(0, 11, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no methods for cell padding as mentioned in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dbvFLggq87k), however you can try their suggested workarounds. For changing cell color, there's [setBackGroundColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundcolor) and to to change font color, there's [setFontColor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontcolorcolor).

Comment: Hello, at first thanks for your answer. Do you have a very smply Sciptexample for mie? Do you have a simply file with the script for me?